# Плавное перемещение QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, анимация

У меня есть QLabel с некой картинкой. И мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки QLabel красиво переместилась на нужные мне координаты. Как это сделать? С помощью чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `Qt` для таких вещей есть специализированная штука – [The Animation Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html).

Взял первый из примеров и немного дописав получил это:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = Qt.QLabel("Animated label", parent=self)
        self.label.move(0, 50)

        self.button = Qt.QPushButton('Start!', parent=self, clicked=self._on_click)

        self.animation = Qt.QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"geometry")
        self.animation.setDuration(10000)
        self.animation.setStartValue(Qt.QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
        self.animation.setEndValue(Qt.QRect(250, 250, 100, 30))

    def _on_click(self):
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(500, 500)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

**PS.** Если анимационный фреймворк overkill для задачи, то сделайте `QTimer` и на его срабатывание меняйте положение виджета

**PPS.** С этим фреймворком не работал, поэтому проблемы и вопросы будут для меня новыми :)

Comment: Хорошо буду изучать)

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap("2.jpg"))
        self.old_pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = Label(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вообще не то имел в виду. Вы двигаете само окно ясен пень что оно двигается. Мне нужно, чтобы в самом окне QLabel перемещалась по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov обновил ответ это то что вам надо?

Comment: Тоже полезно будет, спасибо)

Comment: Зачем усложнять `self.image = QPixmap("2.jpg")`? :)

Comment: @gil9red кто знает, кто знает :D